# How to pass list to cucumber-jvm stepdef in latest 4.x version

Tags: java, regex, list, cucumber-jvm

I have the following Enum

```
public enum Color {
    RED, GREEN, BLUE
}
```

In the feature file I have the following

```
   Then verify policy status flow:RED, GREEN, BLUE
```

In the steps file, I wrote :

```
@Then("verify policy status flow:{colorList}")
public void verifyPolicyStatusFlow(List<Color> myColors) {

}
```

In the class which implements **TypeRegistryConfigurer**, I wrote

```
typeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<List>(
        "colorList",
        "(RED|GREEN|BLUE)(,\b(RED|GREEN|BLUE))*", 
        List.class,
        new Transformer<List>() {
            @Override
            public List<Color> transform(String s) {
                List<Color> collect = Arrays.stream(s.split(", ")).map(e -> Color.valueOf(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                return collect;
            }
        })
);
```

But it doesn't work.
If I change the regular expression pattern to be **"([^']*)"**  it works. But I want the regular expression to be as mutch restrict as possible

Comment: Try replacing the word boundary by a space `(RED|GREEN|BLUE)(, (RED|GREEN|BLUE))*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match the color list RED, GREEN, BLUE  only the first group of the pattern you tried will match 3 times and the second group of the pattern does not match as the space is not being matched.

If you match the space, you can omit the word boundary `\b`

```
(RED|GREEN|BLUE)(, (RED|GREEN|BLUE))*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i3sCTQ/1)

If you are not referring to the groups in the code, you could also make them non capturing:

```
(?:RED|GREEN|BLUE)(?:, (?:RED|GREEN|BLUE))*
```

The pattern `([^']*)` will capture in a group matching 0+ times not a `'` and will also match an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the The fourth birds answer you can also use a `CaptureGroupTransformer` to transform the capture groups in your regex. This avoids the need to split and clean the string.

```
public class TypeRegistryConfiguration implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {
    @Override
    public Locale locale() {
        return Locale.ENGLISH;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
        typeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
                "colorList",
                "(RED|GREEN|BLUE)(?:, (RED|GREEN|BLUE))*",
                List.class,
                new CaptureGroupTransformer<List>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Color> transform(String... args) {
                        return Arrays.stream(args)
                                .map(Color::valueOf)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    }
                })
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! I do not understand when should I use "?:"   and when should I omit it ?

Comment: `?:` indicates that the group is a non capturing group. You want to capture `RED|GREEN|BLUE`, but not the space and comma that precede it. So you have a non capturing group with the space and comma that repeats and inside that group another capturing group that catches the colours.